# Enable JavaScript debugging in Visual Studio 2012 with Edge

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

why in my Visual Studio 2012 I cannot debug JavaScript files?
Appears the hint "The breakpoint will not currently be hit..."
Also using Attach to process -> Script -> msedge.exe
Any idea?
Thank you
Luis

[image]

Comment: 2012? Not a typo? Do you mean 2022 perhaps?

Comment: Exactly 2012. I have to use this old version because is an old project developed with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: @Ciupaz did you find any solution?

Comment: No, not find yet. Sorry.